# Normalized mutual information to evaluate the clustered features

Tags: matlab, validation, cluster-analysis

I'm new in Matlab and I'm trying to implement the normalized mutual information but I got an error.

I'm using the Normalized Mutual Information Function provided by MATHWorks: Normalized Mutual Information
version 1.0 (734 Bytes) by Mo Chen
Fully vectorized implementation NMI. NMI is often used for evaluating clustering results.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function nmi1
    addpath('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Normalization')
     FeaturesFile = dlmread('test.txt');
     [x,y]=size(FeaturesFile);
       z = nmi(x,y);
end
```

and here is the function nmi

```
function z = nmi(x, y)
% Compute normalized mutual information I(x,y)/sqrt(H(x)*H(y)) of two discrete variables x and y.
% Input:
%   x, y: two integer vector of the same length 
% Ouput:
%   z: normalized mutual information z=I(x,y)/sqrt(H(x)*H(y))
% Written by Mo Chen (sth4nth@gmail.com).
assert(numel(x) == numel(y));
n = numel(x);
x = reshape(x,1,n);
y = reshape(y,1,n);

l = min(min(x),min(y));
x = x-l+1;
y = y-l+1;
k = max(max(x),max(y));

idx = 1:n;
Mx = sparse(idx,x,1,n,k,n);
My = sparse(idx,y,1,n,k,n);
Pxy = nonzeros(Mx'*My/n); %joint distribution of x and y
Hxy = -dot(Pxy,log2(Pxy));


% hacking, to elimative the 0log0 issue
Px = nonzeros(mean(Mx,1));
Py = nonzeros(mean(My,1));

% entropy of Py and Px
Hx = -dot(Px,log2(Px));
Hy = -dot(Py,log2(Py));

% mutual information
MI = Hx + Hy - Hxy;

% normalized mutual information
z = sqrt((MI/Hx)*(MI/Hy));
z = max(0,z);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove `function nmi` (the first line of the function): the correct declaration is on your second line.

Comment: thanks@AndreiDavydov. I have edited the post bez this line is went wrongly when I am writing the post. I do not have it in my cod. the problem is already still even without this line.

Comment: Also, in your main code you calculate mutual information on the **size** of the data. Try change `z = nmi(x,y);` to `z = nmi(FeaturesFile(:,1), FeaturesFile(:,2));` (Assume your 'test.txt' file contains many rows and two columns).

Comment: I tried and got the erorr Error in nmi (line 19) Mx = sparse(idx,x,1,n,k,n); and Error in nmi1 (line 5)        z = nmi(FeaturesFile(:,1), FeaturesFile(:,2));

Comment: Seems your `test.txt` file contains non-integer values, but nmi `Compute normalized mutual information of two **discrete** variables x and y.`

Comment: hrere is data in the test.txt, thr first column 0,1,1,1,1 and the second column is 0,1,0,1,0 and now there is no error and no result

Comment: The result saved in your z variable. Just display it: add `disp(z);` after nmi calculation.

Comment: thanks it is working.. but if I have a file contain e.x 100 columns and 40 rows, could i got NMI as one value for the whole file? sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: This depends how you want combine the different columns nmi calculation. If you have file with 100 columns, you get the 100*(100-1)/2 = 4950 nmi calculated values for all column combination. How do you want to combine them?

Comment: Actually all the 100 column are very important and the give good accuracy for me. but how can I combine them? I do not know. could suggest me with how it will done?